# Не могу понять почему мой правильно написанный код не работает. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мой код должен проверять литерал строки на наличие сторонних символов, таких как "+","&","@" и т.д. Но когда я ввожу их, то удаляется лишь определенная часть, и к тому же, если ввести один символ "+" в инпут, то произойдет ошибка. Пожалуйста, обьясните почему код не удаляет копии одного символа, то есть все символы. Прошу, помогите разобраться, я уже совсем отчаялся.

```
inp = list(input())

i = 0

while i != len(inp):
    if not inp[i].isalnum():
        del inp[i]
        
    i+=1

print(inp)
```

Comment: *"код должен проверять литерал строки на наличие сторонних символов"* - тогда с какого дуба он что-то удаляет?

Comment: этот вопрос появляется здесь с завидной регулярностью... Ответ - не изменяйте строку по которой идет итерация в цикле - это путь полный суровых бронебойных граблей :-D PS `res = "".join([x for x in inp if x. isalnum()])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому как длинна меняется и i оказывается за границами на последних операциях. Проход по списку или строке с удалением только в обратном направлении:

```
i = len(inp)
while i:
    i-=1
    if not inp[i].isalnum():
        del inp[i]
```

И это тоже является плохим кодом.

Используйте только фильтры для таких задач:

```
inp = ''.join(filter(lambda x: x.isalnum(), inp))
```

Еще плохой, но рабочий вариант:

```
i = 0
while i != len(inp):
    if not inp[i].isalnum():
        del inp[i]
    else:
        i+=1
```

Comment: спасибо большое вам! третий вариант - это то решение, которое я искал. Но почему ваша вариация кода работает исправно, а моя нет? можно, пожалуйста, обьяснить? @eri

Comment: @MangoJuice - Потому как длинна меняется и i оказывается за границами на последних операциях в вашем варианте

Comment: @eri Не поэтому, а потому что нумерация съезжает и следующий элемент пропускается из-за этого )  С длиной тут как-раз всё нормально поскольку `len` проверяется в условии цикла )  Так что объяснение у вас в ответе не совсем правильное )

Comment: @CrazyElf точно! Надо уточнить ответ

Answer (score 3):

сколько раз повторять - **НЕЛЬЗЯ** удалять элементы списка по которому вы при этом еще и двигаетесь!!!

и зачем вообще удалять символы, наоборот - оставляйте нужные символы и формируйте из них новую строку

```
res = ''.join(letter for letter in input() if letter.isalnum())

print(res)
```

P.S.

а у вас происходит следующее - вы удаляете элемент, список уменьшается на 1 элемент, вы при этом делаете еще `i += 1`, т.е. еще на 1 символ сдвигаетесь, так что во-первых часть символов будет выпадать из анализа, а во вторых появляется шанс просто попасть уже за пределы списка

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ, но я хочу именно удалять эти символы. Как мне исправить код, что бы он начал работать исправно? Именно мой код. Я хочу исправить свой код.

Comment: кваддратные скобки лишние

Comment: тогда идите с конца списка к началу,

Comment: @eri, верно! подправил

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае можно просто вынести `i+=1` в блок `else`:

```
inp = list(input())
i = 0
while i != len(inp):
    if not inp[i].isalnum():
        del inp[i]
    else:
        i+=1
print(inp)
```

Хотя другие отвечающие и комментаторы правы - лучше так не делать (не удалять элементы из списка по которому проходите), в других обстоятельствах это может привести к весьма неприятным багам.

Comment: Одновременно пришла мысль про элс)